# service worker showing as deleted even though registration was successful

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I can't seem to figure out any reason why a service worker would be deleted with the code that I have that registers or actually is the service worker.

But in this site, it shows up as **deleted** in the Service Workers section of the chrome dev tools (image below).

Yet it is also registering properly as logged in the console (same image below).

[image]

Here is the service worker registration code:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/earnie.min.js', { scope: '/'}).then(function(registration){
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
}).catch(function(error){
        console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
    });
}
```

Here is the service worker code:

```
var cachename="e2",cachelist=";;.;/;./;/privacyPolicy.html;/css/main.css;/css/normalize.css;".split(";");

self.addEventListener("install",function(a){
    a.waitUntil(caches.open(cachename).then(function(a){
        return a.addAll(cachelist)
    }))
});
self.addEventListener("fetch",function(a){
    a.respondWith(caches.match(a.request).then(function(b){
        return b?b:fetch(a.request.clone(), { credentials: 'include', redirect: 'follow' })
    }))
});
```

What is causing it to be deleted and not registering?

Comment: Did you solve the issue,  am facing similar kind of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199281/service-worker-showing-as-deleted-after-reloading-the-page-but-register-for-the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registration succeeded, but installation actually fails.  Your `waitUntil()` promise is  not resolving, which causes `InstallEvent` event to fail, thus deleting the ServiceWorker. `cachelist` probably returns invalid/empty values when you run `split(';')`

I recommend ensuring that `cachelist` is an array with valid URI values, then you can debug within the install event**

```
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cachename)
    .then(cache => cache.addAll(cachelist))
    .catch(error => console.error('', error))
  )
})
```

**You'll most likely need "Preserve log" console option enabled in Chrome Dev Tools to see the console error.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a mix of permissions issues on some of the files it seems and also mistyped URIs. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @anthumChris, am facing same kinda issue my service worker registered succesfully, but when i reload the page, it shows as deleted, may i know how to solve this one?

Comment: @anthumChris can you answer my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199281/service-worker-showing-as-deleted-after-reloading-the-page-but-register-for-the

Answer (score 0):

Check for console errors, I was having the issue where the service worker would get deleted for something totally unrelated to the implementation. It was a faulty iframe in the html. Service workers are very basic things so the implementation is very straight forward, the gotcha is, your existing code. While it might work as intended, an error or competing service worker could cause the service worker to fail its installation.